# Send login data from Core PHP to Codeigniter via Curl

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I want to send post data from Core PHP login to CodeIgniter login. How to send this data. In this section, I am using CURL, but I cannot find the exact solution.

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question) and [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $url = 'http://example.com/user/login'; 
    $post_fields=array('email'=>$_POST['user_email'],'password'=>$_POST['user_password']);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($post_fields)); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_fields)); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
```